# Django redirect doesn't reach the root url

Tags: django

Looks like `redirect(<url>)` is adding `<url>` to the current view url, ignoring `urls.py`, with respect to the **Code** below redirecting to "`<mydomain>.com/savePersonalEdits/account/`" while what I wanted is: "`<mydomain>.com/account/`"

**Code:**

At the end of some Django view function I have:

`return redirect('account/')`

urls:

```
path('account/', views.accountSettings),
path('savePersonalEdits/', views.saveEdits, name="savePersonalEdits") #name needed for HTML form action url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HttpResopnseRedirect for this

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    


return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/')
```

also there is a better way to redirect, create `name` your path in `ulrs.py`

```
path('account/', views.accountSettings, name="account_url_name"),

#and in your views import reverse and HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("account_url_name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
return redirect('/account/')
```

**or**

```
return redirect('account')
```